# In UItableview, when I scroll table values are miss placing(values selecting from picker)

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image]

Here I am trying to do dynamic `UITableViewCell` with `UIPickerView`.
Step 1:
     In Custom cell, I took 1 label and 1 `UITextField`.
Step 2:
    used downpickerview library for data displaying and data fetching.
Step 3:
using below code I can able to select data, but after that, if I scroll `UITableView` data will be miss placing.

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"Cell";

    customCell *cell1=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell1 == nil)
    {
        cell1 = [[customCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    }

    cell1.productTitleLabel.text =[arrProductTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    self.downPicker = [[DownPicker alloc] initWithTextField:cell1.productvalueTextfield withData:arrProductVal];

    [self.downPicker addTarget:self action:@selector(measurementSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [cell1.contentView addSubview:self.downPicker];

    return cell1;
}
```

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

`UITableViewCell` values are misplacing because you haven't set the data for other cells, You need to store the values in an array and just update the values from there and it will work. :)

Answer (score 0):

Something is not right with your code:

```
cell1.productTitleLabel.text =[arrProductTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

self.downPicker = [[DownPicker alloc] initWithTextField:cell1.productvalueTextfield withData:arrProductVal];

[self.downPicker addTarget:self action:@selector(measurementSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[cell1.contentView addSubview:self.downPicker];
```

Bear in mind that in iOS, a tableView will reuse its cells. So when you scroll your `UITableView`, it will reuse the old cells which were created before, and
   `[cell1.contentView addSubview:self.downPicker];` Will be executed everytime a cell is reused, as a result, you will end up having many downPicker objects in one cell.

Comment: I also felt same, let me know if you have solution for this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you should add the DownPicker directly onto the cell itself (inside the init method of customCell class),  then declare a delegate inside the cell and set your VC as the cell's delegate. Then each time the downPicker is selected/tapped, call the delegate method to handle the event using the cell's indexpath.

Comment: i found solution it's working fine, but it's different approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.navigationItem.title = @"DETAILS";
_dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
arrProductTitle = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"title0",@"title1",@"title2",@"title3",@"title4",@"title5",@"title6",@"title7",@"title8",@"title9",@"title10",@"title11",@"title12",@"title13",@"title14",@"title15", nil];
arrProductVal = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"0",@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",nil];}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return arrProductTitle.count-1;}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"Cell";

customCell *cell1=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

if (cell1 == nil)
{
    cell1 = [[customCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
}

cell1.productTitleLabel.text =[arrProductTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"%@",_dict);
NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row]);

if (_dict[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row]]) {
    cell1.productvalueTextfield.text =[_dict valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row]];
}
else {
    cell1.productvalueTextfield.text = @"";
    self.downPicker = [[DownPicker alloc] initWithTextField:cell1.productvalueTextfield withData:arrProductVal];
    self.downPicker.tag = indexPath.row;

    [self.downPicker addTarget:self action:@selector(measurementSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [cell1.contentView addSubview:self.downPicker];
}
return cell1;}

-(void)measurementSelected:(id)dp {
NSString* selectedValue = [dp text];
NSString* selectedIndex = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)[dp tag]];
[_dict setValue:[dp text] forKey:selectedIndex];
NSLog(@"_dict: %@",_dict);

NSLog(@"SELECTED TAG:::::::%ld",[dp tag]);
NSLog(@"SELECTED VALUE:::::::%@",selectedValue);
NSLog(@"SELECTED INDEX VALUEEEEEEEEEEE:::::::%ld",[dp selectedIndex]);}
```

https://github.com/gvniosdev/Dynamic-UItableview-with-Picker-Selection